# Jquery show effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery, show

this is the HTML one:

```
<section class="navbar-sticky-btn-body" id="back-top">
    <a>
        <img src="../Images/Shared/BackToTop.png" />
    </a>
</section>
```

and the jquery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();
    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('#back-top').show("fold", null, 500);
            } else {
                $('#back-top').hide("fold", null, 500);
            }
        });
        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

as you see i use the fold effect to be applied to showing function but every effect i use i see the same result!

i should have make a silly mistake but unfortunately i can't fix it!

Comment: Did you include effects plugin?

Comment: Have you included jquery UI ? if not please include it from http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: no! what is that? i just used the thing as here"http://jqueryui.com/show/"!

Comment: And where is element having id back-top ?

Comment: download another version of jquery UI which include effect fucntions.http://jqueryui.com/download/ . Let me know if the issue is resolved

Comment: @ConductedClever : working?

Comment: I have problem by adding new javascript library to ASP.NET MVC project. Give me a while.

Comment: dunno if i'm blind or something... but your selector for show() and hide() is #back-top - and i can't find an id="backtop" in your html. so, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: @errand I have fixed it in my question! the thing isn't this.

Comment: @conducted which js libraries have you included? jquery-ui needs jquery, but show(), hide() are already available with jquery - so you won't need jq-ui just for this case...

is there a css definition for your element, that does something like:  visibility: hidden, show() and hide() won't work

Comment: @errand i have included both jquery and jquery ui libraries and the css rules are ok. as i said, the show/hide operations are working fine but the effect doesn't apply!

Comment: @Shiv your solution was right. make your answer as an answer instead of comment to check it as true. i didn't think that the default jquery library that asp.net mvc adds to solution is not that complete!

Comment: @ConductedClever : I have added this as answer, please mark. thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download another version of jquery UI which include "Effect"  functions (check it as true) from  [jqueryui.com/download](http://jqueryui.com/download/) .

Answer (score 0):

In that code you want to show something when you scroll down, right? But if it is at the top of the page you will no see it. If that is the case you should add somethig like this to the CSS:

```
#back-top{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

Also, it will make the animation every time, so you have to check if the element is hide or not to make the animation:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    if($('#back-top').css("display")=="none"){
         $('#back-top').show("fold", null, 500);
    }
} else {
   $('#back-top').hide("fold", null, 500);
}
```

And be sure to add jQuery and jQuery UI.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6uekkee/2/) working